# Details element, fit to content whilst inside a flex box, even when collapsed

Tags: html, css, flexbox, html-tag-details

When placing an `<details>` element inside a `<div>` with `display: flex` the width of the `<details>` element will equal the `<summary>` element when collapsed and will grow when uncollapsed to fit its content.

Example:

```css
.flex {
  display: flex;
}

details {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex">
  <details>
    <summary> short </summary>
    <p> very long and detailed description </p>
  </details>
</div>
```

What I want is that the width of the `<details>` element is consistent regardless if it is collapsed or not. Ideally such that it fits its content.

In short how do I prevent it from shrinking when collapsed.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by setting a fixed width on the details element.

```css
details {
  background-color: red;
  width: 50px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Specify a `flex-basis` on `details`.

```css
.flex {
  display: flex;
}

details {
  background-color: red;
  flex-basis: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex">
  <details>
    <summary> short </summary>
    <p> very long and detailed description </p>
  </details>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try code below: Hope helpful for you

```css
.flex {
  display: flex;
}

details {
  background-color: green;
  flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex">
  <details>
    <summary> short </summary>
    <p> very long and detailed description </p>
  </details>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

solution, you need min 1 li

```
 <details>
    <summary> <li></li> short </summary>
    <p> very long and detailed description </p>
  </details>
```

so when you will put flex on summary , you will have a arrow